# Rectangle with cutted triangle

Tags: css

How to make something like that in css?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ol23la6ey373gt/example.png]

Comment: answer i have added has not a transparent background because making its color transparent will show the parent div background but still you can use `border-image` property like this in .up class: `border-image:url('myimage.jpg');`

Answer (score 1):

you can add a border-image in .up to see full clone effect of above image!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRC4Q/)

```
div.wrapper {
    background:#d89043;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
div.up {
  width:0px; 
  height:0px; 
  border-left:50px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
  border-right:50px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
  border-bottom:50px solid #fff; /* bottom, add background color here */
  font-size:0px;
  line-height:0px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  margin-left:40%;
}​
```